# How do I make sure that there is one NHibernate ISession per request using Autofac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, dependency-injection, autofac

I have the following code in an Autofac Module that is used in my Application_Start method:

```
builder.Register(c => new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory())
    .SingletonScoped();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
    .HttpRequestScoped();

builder.Register<NHibernateSomethingRepository>().As<ISomethingRepository>();
```

The constructor for the repository takes an ISession as argument. But I end up with one session for the whole application, even though I explicitly asked for it to be HttpRequestScoped.

I have configured the ContainerDisposal HTTP module.

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DeterministicDisposal) you have to create a nested container, but I'm letting Autofac autowire the dependencies.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem, so I will answer my own question.

I registered my repository with the default scope, which in Autofac is singleton scope. I should have done this:

```
builder.Register<NHibernateSomethingRepository>()
    .As<ISomethingRepository>()
    .HttpRequestScoped;
```

Comment: NOTE: In Autofac2 the default has changed - it is now:  'factoryScoped' AKA 'InstancePerDependancy' in the new parlance.